# Getting row count from ResultSet in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database, count, resultset

I have a form that is connected to my database via JDBC and I have created a method that I intend to print out the number of rows in my tables as follow:

```
public static void getRowCount(String sql, PrintWriter printThis)
{
   try
   {
       Connection c = // Another function called from a different class that handles the connection
       PreparedStatement p = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(sql);
       ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();

       while (r.next())
       {
           printThis.println(r.toString());
       }
        c.close();
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

If I pass an sql string `"Select COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;"` as a parameter, it should print out the number of rows for my table.  For example, if I currently have 4 rows in MyTable, it should print `4`  But all it's printing out is an object with random numbers and letters:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@7e11fc40
```

How do I display the result of my sql query after passing it to my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 r.getInt("totalCount");
```

change the query as `"Select COUNT(*) as totalCount  FROM MyTable;"`

if you want to use `printThis`, pass the `r` as the parameter in the function and get the integer value within the function using `getInt` method in resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Since the resultset will contain only one column you can simply use column index number which is 1.

`r.getInt(1);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change to This line `printThis.println(r.toString());`

and add as this `printThis.println(r.getInt(1));` OR `System.out.println(r.getInt(1));`